# Table performance / general performance / vectorizing

Tags: matlab, performance

I implemented a 4D Interpolation in matlab, where performance is really important. The interpolation method is a nearest neighbor interpolation based on a delaunay triangulation. As I am quite new to matlab coding, I want to ask, if I should use arrays or cells instead of tables, because of their poor performance. Also the general question, if you see anything, where I can speed up my code. I already saved the mat files in v6 so this is not an option. Below the text you see the code of the main program. After that the code for the 2D interpolation.

The tables I loaded in consist of 7 columns filled with AeroDataId, X_C coordinate, CP (pressure derivative), Mach number, lift coefficient, ReynoldsNumber and Transition. One AeroDataId belongs to in the most cases 280 x_c coordinates with the different pressure coefficients.

Filtering all the data seems to be faster than using SQL queries.

```
clc
close
clear


%% ReynoldsNumbers and Transitions known in the database

ReynoldsNumbers=[1e6;1.5e6;2.5e6;5e6;8e6;14e6;25e6;50e6;100e6];
Transition=[0;0.1;0.2;0.3;0.4;0.5;0.6;0.7;0.8;0.9];

%% parameters

Ma=0.85;
C_l=0.345;
Tl=0.15;
Re=55e6;
AirfoilId=0;

delta=0.015;
delta_ini=0.15;

%% try to find the neighbours of the parameters, which already exist in the database
tic
Re_u=ReynoldsNumbers(ReynoldsNumbers==Re);
Tl_u=Transition(Transition==Tl);
Tl_o=[];
Re_o=[];


if isempty(Re_u)
    Re_u_index=nearestpoint(Re,ReynoldsNumbers,'previous');
    Re_o_index=nearestpoint(Re,ReynoldsNumbers,'next');
    Re_o=ReynoldsNumbers(Re_o_index);
    Re_u=ReynoldsNumbers(Re_u_index);
    if Re < 1e6
        Re_u=1e6;
        Re_o=1.5e6;
    elseif Re > 100e6
        Re_u=50e6;
        Re_o=100e6;
    end
end
 
if isempty(Tl_u)
    Tl_u_index=nearestpoint(Tl,Transition,'previous');
    Tl_o_index=nearestpoint(Tl,Transition,'next');
    Tl_u=Transition(Tl_u_index);
    Tl_o=Transition(Tl_o_index);
end
toc
%% load data based on the airfoilId size of new_upper_airfoil 25000000x7 table

if AirfoilId==0
    load('new_upper_airfoil_all_0');
    load('new_lower_airfoil_all_0');
elseif AirfoilId==1
    load('new_upper_airfoil_all_1');
    load('new_lower_airfoil_all_1');
elseif AirfoilId==2
    load('new_upper_airfoil_all_2');
    load('new_lower_airfoil_all_2');
end

%% no need to to make all the interpolation with the whole data, only a specific delta 

new_upper_airfoil=new_upper_airfoil_all(new_upper_airfoil_all.Ma < (Ma+delta_ini) & new_upper_airfoil_all.Ma > (Ma-delta_ini) & new_upper_airfoil_all.CL_res < (C_l+delta_ini) & new_upper_airfoil_all.CL_res > (C_l-delta_ini),2:7);
new_lower_airfoil=new_lower_airfoil_all(new_lower_airfoil_all.Ma < (Ma+delta_ini) & new_lower_airfoil_all.Ma > (Ma-delta_ini) & new_lower_airfoil_all.CL_res < (C_l+delta_ini) & new_lower_airfoil_all.CL_res > (C_l-delta_ini),2:7);

%% filter data for the first 2D - Interpoaltion and execute it

new_upper_airfoil1=new_upper_airfoil(new_upper_airfoil.ReynoldsNumber==Re_u & new_upper_airfoil.Transition==Tl_u,1:4);
new_lower_airfoil1=new_lower_airfoil(new_lower_airfoil.ReynoldsNumber==Re_u & new_lower_airfoil.Transition==Tl_u,1:4);
DV1=delaunay_nearest(new_upper_airfoil1, new_lower_airfoil1, Ma, C_l, delta);
DV_1=table(DV1.X_C, DV1.CP, repmat(Re_u,280,1),repmat(Tl_u,280,1),'VariableNames',{'X_C','CP','Re','Tl'});
%% secound

if ~isempty(Tl_o)
    new_upper_airfoil2=new_upper_airfoil(new_upper_airfoil.ReynoldsNumber==Re_u & new_upper_airfoil.Transition==Tl_o,1:4);
    new_lower_airfoil2=new_lower_airfoil(new_lower_airfoil.ReynoldsNumber==Re_u & new_lower_airfoil.Transition==Tl_o,1:4);
    DV2=delaunay_nearest(new_upper_airfoil2, new_lower_airfoil2, Ma, C_l, delta);
    DV_2=table(DV2.X_C, DV2.CP, repmat(Re_u,280,1), repmat(Tl_o,280,1),'VariableNames',{'X_C','CP','Re','Tl'});
else
    DV_2=[];
end

%% third

if ~isempty(Re_o)
    new_upper_airfoil3=new_upper_airfoil(new_upper_airfoil.ReynoldsNumber==Re_o & new_upper_airfoil.Transition==Tl_u,1:4);
    new_lower_airfoil3=new_lower_airfoil(new_lower_airfoil.ReynoldsNumber==Re_o & new_lower_airfoil.Transition==Tl_u,1:4);
    DV3=delaunay_nearest(new_upper_airfoil3, new_lower_airfoil3, Ma, C_l, delta);
    DV_3=table(DV3.X_C, DV3.CP, repmat(Re_o,280,1),repmat(Tl_u,280,1),'VariableNames',{'X_C','CP','Re','Tl'});
else
    DV_3=[];
end    

%% fourth

if ~isempty(Re_o) && ~isempty(Tl_o)
    new_upper_airfoil4=new_upper_airfoil(new_upper_airfoil.ReynoldsNumber==Re_o & new_upper_airfoil.Transition==Tl_o,1:4);
    new_lower_airfoil4=new_lower_airfoil(new_lower_airfoil.ReynoldsNumber==Re_o & new_lower_airfoil.Transition==Tl_o,1:4);
    DV4=delaunay_nearest(new_upper_airfoil4, new_lower_airfoil4, Ma, C_l, delta);  
    DV_4=table(DV4.X_C, DV4.CP, repmat(Re_o,280,1),repmat(Tl_o,280,1),'VariableNames',{'X_C','CP','Re','Tl'});
else
    DV_4=[];
end

%% Interpolation of the 4 2D Interpolations

DV_inter=[DV_1;DV_2;DV_3;DV_4];

if size(DV_inter,1)==280
    DV=DV_1(:,1:2);
    
%     figure
%     hold on
%     plot(DV.X_C,-DV.CP,'bl-');
%     grid on;
%     xlabel('X_C');
%     ylabel('Cp');
%     
    
else
    %% interpolation with inverse distance weighted interpoaltion
    load('x_c0');
    DV=zeros(281,2);
    for x_c=1:1:280
        x_c_inter=x_c0(x_c);
        Find=DV_inter(DV_inter.X_C==x_c_inter,:);
        
        cp_inter=IDW(Find.Re, Find.Tl,Find.CP,Re,Tl,-2,'ng',2);

        DV(x_c,:)=[x_c_inter,cp_inter];
       
    end
    DV(281,:)=DV(1,:);
    
    figure
    hold on
    plot(DV(:,1),-DV(:,2),'r-');
    grid on;
    xlabel('X_C');
    ylabel('Cp');
end
```

```
function DV = delaunay_nearest(new_upper_airfoil,new_lower_airfoil,Ma,C_l,delta)
Error=true;

load('x_c0');
while(Error)
    %% build table for the pressure distribution
    DV=array2table(zeros(280,2),'VariableNames',{'X_C','CP'});
   
    %% another smaller delta for the interpolation (if too small the exception will be catched and the interpolation is restarted with a higher delta
    
    new_upper_airfoil_loop=new_upper_airfoil(new_upper_airfoil.Ma < (Ma+delta) & new_upper_airfoil.Ma > (Ma-delta) & new_upper_airfoil.CL_res < (C_l+delta) & new_upper_airfoil.CL_res > (C_l-delta),:);
    new_lower_airfoil_loop=new_lower_airfoil(new_lower_airfoil.Ma < (Ma+delta) & new_lower_airfoil.Ma > (Ma-delta) & new_lower_airfoil.CL_res < (C_l+delta) & new_lower_airfoil.CL_res > (C_l-delta),:);
    

    %% try to build the delaunay triangulation
    try
        DT=delaunayTriangulation(new_upper_airfoil_loop.Ma,new_upper_airfoil_loop.CL_res);
        
%         figure
%         hold on;
%         triplot(DT);
%         plot(Ma,C_l,'ro');
        %% find nearest neighbor
        pointindex=dsearchn(DT.Points,[Ma,C_l]);
        point=DT.Points(pointindex,:);
        Error=0;
    catch
        delta=delta+0.005;
        disp('Die Deltas wurden um 0.005 erhöht, da der Bereich der Daten zu klein war.');
        continue;
    end

    %% search for the nearest neighbor
    new_upper_airfoil_loop=new_upper_airfoil_loop(new_upper_airfoil_loop.Ma==point(1,1) & new_upper_airfoil_loop.CL_res==point(1,2),1:2);
    new_lower_airfoil_loop=new_lower_airfoil_loop(new_lower_airfoil_loop.Ma==point(1,1) & new_lower_airfoil_loop.CL_res==point(1,2),1:2);
    
    %% 2D Interpolation for all 280 points of the airfoil with the same x/c coordinates
    for x_c=1:1:280
            x_c_inter=x_c0(x_c);

            %% upper_airfoil
            if x_c < 146
                FIND=new_upper_airfoil_loop(abs(new_upper_airfoil_loop.X_C-x_c_inter)<0.0005,:);
                
                if(isempty(FIND))

                    leftNeighborIndex=nearestpoint(x_c_inter,new_upper_airfoil_loop.X_C,'previous');
                    if isnan(leftNeighborIndex)
                        leftNeighborIndex=1;
                    end

                    rightNeighborIndex=leftNeighborIndex+1;

                    if rightNeighborIndex > height(new_upper_airfoil_loop)
                        rightNeighborIndex=leftNeighborIndex-1;
                    end

                    average=interp1([new_upper_airfoil_loop.X_C(leftNeighborIndex,:),new_upper_airfoil_loop.X_C(rightNeighborIndex,:)], [new_upper_airfoil_loop.CP(leftNeighborIndex,:),new_upper_airfoil_loop.CP(rightNeighborIndex,:)], x_c_inter, 'linear','extrap');
                    FIND.X_C(1,:)=x_c_inter;
                    FIND.CP(1,:)=average; 


                    DV(x_c,:)=FIND;

                else
                    FIND.X_C(1,1)=x_c_inter;
                    DV(x_c,:)=FIND(1,:);

                end 

            end
            %% lower airfoil
            if x_c > 145
                FIND=new_lower_airfoil_loop(abs(new_lower_airfoil_loop.X_C-x_c_inter)<0.00008,:);

                if(isempty(FIND))

                    leftNeighborIndex=nearestpoint(x_c_inter,new_lower_airfoil_loop.X_C,'previous');
                    if isnan(leftNeighborIndex)
                        leftNeighborIndex=height(new_lower_airfoil_loop);
                    end
                    rightNeighborIndex=leftNeighborIndex-1;

                    average=interp1([new_lower_airfoil_loop.X_C(leftNeighborIndex,:),new_lower_airfoil_loop.X_C(rightNeighborIndex,:)], [new_lower_airfoil_loop.CP(leftNeighborIndex,:),new_lower_airfoil_loop.CP(rightNeighborIndex,:)], x_c_inter, 'linear','extrap');
                    FIND.X_C(1,:)=x_c_inter;
                    FIND.CP(1,:)=average; 


                    DV(x_c,:)=FIND;

                else
                    FIND.X_C(1,1)=x_c_inter;
                    DV(x_c,:)=FIND(1,:);
                end 

            end
        

    end

end

end
```

Comment: I think your question is too broad. It seems to me that you multiple questions and one of them is a request to spot anything that can speed up your code. Please note that you should have one clearly defined question per post. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That might help you to make it more focused.

Comment: I agree with @kkuilla your question is rather broad. I would recommend trying to figure out parts of your question by running some experiments. E.g. build two versions of the same code one using array or cells and one using tables and measure their respective performance using tic/toc. Slim down your question to the things you can't make headway with

Comment: Okay, thank you guys. I implemenented the whole program with arrays and now it runs mor than 4 times faster. But can you maybe help me vectorize the code?

Comment: @matlabhelp Profile the code, see where you're spending the most time, then create a [mre] concentrating on *one* problem. "Reverse engineer a couple hundred lines of code and improve it for me" is not a very reasonable thing to ask of volunteers and is off-topic for Stack Overflow.